# Material UI, React and styling some, not all, components

Tags: reactjs, datatables, material-ui

I have a datatable that outputs something like this in React using material UI.

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root MuiTab-textColorPrimary Mui-selected MuiTab-fullWidth" tabindex="0" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
    <span class="MuiTab-wrapper">ASIC Notification</span>
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
</button>
```

Pretty standard output for Material UI content. I am styling this material UI content by wrapping my app in this

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    MuiTab: {
        textColorPrimary: {
            color: "white !important" //White tab text color
        },
        '&$selected': {
            color: "#182033 !important" //Dark tab text select color
        }
    }
}
```

This works and changes the styles as I want. However whenever I use the MUI Datatable `import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";` They all share these classes and I need to style the second one different;y.

How can I namespace a table so only that table is effected with certain styles?

Thanks

Comment: If you include a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that demonstrates your problem, it will be much easier for someone to help you with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering the same thing, in terms of different styles Material UI offers a `color` prop for most components which switch the theme styles of a component, however there is no clear documentation on how to go about extending these APIs with your own theme colors e.g. `primary` `secondary` `facebook` `danger` what have you.